# React production build Uncaught RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds

Tags: reactjs

In my react application i am using deepar sdk for augmented reality, In local it is running and working but in live server it is
not detecting the looks. because in production server i am using production build .

```
  deepar.wasm:0x374e4 Uncaught RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[1354]:0x374e4
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[629]:0xd25c
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[2072]:0x62d6e
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[572]:0xac58
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[410]:0x68f2
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[1065]:0x257f5
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[3985]:0xf4b3c
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[2121]:0x6413d
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[3833]:0xef340
      at Me (https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.wasm:wasm-function[2364]:0x6ae0f)
      at e._switchEffect (https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.js:1:62688)
      at Aa (https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.js:1:11168)
      at https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.js:1:66044
      at Object.e.switchEffectByteArray (https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.js:1:2344)
      at XMLHttpRequest.l.onreadystatechange (https://baby-try-on-dot-byytes-286402.uc.r.appspot.com/lib/deepar.js:1:2572)
```

What might be the issue ? Please have a look

Comment: any update on this?